# datatables: json issue in webkit

Tags: javascript

This is my json returned:

```
{ "aaData": [["15/10/2010",".tv","All / Unidentified","Streaming","7","1.33","30%","0.4"],
["08/10/2010",".tv","All / Unidentified","Streaming","30","5.7","30%","1.71"],
["Total","","","","90","17.1","","5.13"],] }
```

Which works fine in Firefox, its input into the table, however in Chrome and Safari I get: DataTables warning: JSON data from server failed to load or be parsed. This is most likely to be caused by a JSON formatting error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing i see that might cause an issue is the comma after the last element of the array of arrays (between the closing brackets).  Technically, it's not valid -- items are separated by commas, so what should come after the comma is another entry, not the closing bracket.  But some implementations allow it.

EDIT:  Confirmed -- with the comma, Chrome fails to parse...without it, works fine.